# Content Offset of UIScrollView changes with iphone screen size

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit

My UIScrollView.contentOffset.y field is very inconsistent when using different sized iPhones.  For some reason, when I use different size screens, the content offset varies. Across all screens, I have a UIView that is CONSISTENTLY placed at y = 331.5 (although in reality its more like 578 because my Navbar has a height of 148.0, so 331.5 + 148.0 = 579.5).

However, when I use different size screens, there is always a different contentOffset.y variable.  The following are the ScrollView.contentOffset.y values for different screens when I scroll and put my UIView at the top of each screen, right below the NavBar.

- iPhone 12 Max: 550.0
- iPhone 12: 520.0
- iPhone 11: 538.0
- iPhone 8: 490.0
- iPod (7th gen): 455

I have no idea why this happens and it is super frustrating, because I am trying to have this UIView (which, as I said, is ALWAYS placed at y=331.5 regardless of screen-size), "stick" to the Navbar and scroll with my screen after I scroll past it.  However, I clearly can't do that if I do not have an accurate reference of where my UIScrollView has scrolled.

I have already tried setting up proportions among the different screen-sizes and it causes everything to get super inaccurate.

Does anyone know any other UIScrollView variables I could use for this or any other way to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: From what you've described, the contentOffset.y seems to be working as it should. What exactly is it that you're trying to achieve? Perhaps more detail about what you're trying to achieve could make it easier for someone to provide a better approach

Comment: Did you try setting UIScrollView's contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior ?

Comment: Hello! I think you can try to not change contentOffSet but set constraints for scrollView instead.